# html_text ( from rvest) returns character(o) using gadget selector

Tags: rvest

Hello I'm using gadgetselector  to get the code to get the info from a page:

here are  my commands :

```
page <- read_html("https://yoopies.fr/recherche-aide-a-domicile/results?auto=1&c=paris")

References <- page %>% 
     html_nodes (".experience") %>%
     html_text()
```

The results is not an error message but character(0) whereas in this case i should get "24 ans , pas d'expérience"

When i select the info i want t extract gadgetelector indicates me ".experience"
When i inspect i get this line :

```
<div data-v-8eb13c4c="" class="experience">
           ** 24 ans, Pas d'expérience**
        </div>
```

maybe those line are not html ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Laurent! Welcome! Those lines look like HTML to me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to browse through some past Q&As about rvest and javascript - https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5brvest%5d%20javascript&searchOn=3

Comment: ah yes looking at it now- did you attempt to load the page with Javascript disabled Laurent?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Mark, I just tried to disable Javascript for this but then i get a with page ! So i think thereis a layer of JS in that page. Nothing shows Maybe this means that i should Rselenium instead ?